# Motorola E (2nd gen) reboots when installing release apk but not when installing debug apk

Tags: android, installation, apk, release, reboot

I am developing a new Android app and have run into a weird issue.

When I install the 'release' version of the app on a Motorola E (2nd gen) the complete phone hangs and reboots after a couple of minutes. It does not matter if I install from the Play Store or over USB using adb, the behavior is the same.

Installing the 'debug' version (over USB) works fine, the app runs great after installing.

I happen to have two almost identical Motorole E (2nd gen) devices and the problem happens on both of them! All other (5+) devices I have tested on work fine, those are all newer devices though.

- I have tried disabling aapt2 (android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties).
- I have tried forcing installation on internal storage (android:installLocation="internalOnly" in Manifest).

But these changes did not fix the problem.

- The release version (currently in closed alpha) does not use proguard (yet).
- Multidex is enabled, both on the release and debug versions.
- compileSdkVersion=27

If I keep an 'adb shell' open during installation of the release version the commandline gets progressively less responsive until it hangs. 'dex2oat' seems to be on top of the process list at the end even though it only takes 1% cpu time.

Any tips on how to proceed to debug this issue are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. A huge library was included in the apk, making the code size explode to over 5MB. Dex2oat was using so much memory when compiling the code that it eventually crashed the device.

Refactoring my project so the huge library (used by offline tools in my project but not by the Android part) was no longer included fixed the issue.